# DatePicker not using all of screen space in android

Tags: android, datepicker, tablet

I am currently working on an application which displays a DatePicker in a fragment. Although when I attempt to display the datepicker within the following xml layout, it display the datepicker with large gaps on either side when viewing it on a tablet. ( picture: [Datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyAEa.png)
). 
 
Is there anyway that the date pickers size can be increased so it fills a larger portion of the screen or is this just the default size for the datepicker set by android?

```
    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dialog_date_date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My implementation code:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Date date = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    final int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    final int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
            .inflate(R.layout.datepicker_masterdetail, null);

    mDatePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_date_picker);
    mDatePicker.init(year, month, day, null);

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(view)
            .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            int year = mDatePicker.getYear();
                            int month = mDatePicker.getMonth();
                            int day = mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                            Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute).getTime();
                            sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, date);
                        }
                    })
            .create();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.You can play around with `android:scaleX` and `android:scaleY` which every value fits with your need. go with it.

```
 <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dialog_date_date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="0.60"
        android:scaleY="0.60"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
```